# How to use custom function for color text across all chapters of RBookdown?

Tags: r, yaml, bookdown

I'm using RBookdown with multiple chapters such as [this minimal example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo).

In order to have color fonts in both html and pdf formats [section 5.1.1 here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html) provides the colorize function

```
colorize <- function(x, color) {
if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
  sprintf("\\textcolor{%s}{%s}", color, x)
} else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
  sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>", color,
    x)
} else x 
}
```

This is great and I want to use it, but I don't know where to put it.  If I put it inside the [YAML header](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/yaml-options.html) like so

````
 --- 
 title: "A Minimal Book Example"
 author: "Yihui Xie"
 date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
 site: bookdown::bookdown_site
 output: bookdown::gitbook
 documentclass: book
 bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
 biblio-style: apalike
 link-citations: yes
 github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
 description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
 ```{r}
 colorize <- function(x, color) {
 if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
 sprintf("\\textcolor{%s}{%s}", color, x)
 } else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
 sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>", 
 color,
 x)
 } else x
 }
 ```
 ---
````

this is clearly the wrong path because of error message

```
 Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
   Scanner error: while scanning for the next token
```

However, if I try to put the colorize function within the body of an Rmd file such as

````
 # Prerequisites
 ```{r}
 colorize <- function(x, color) {
 if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
 sprintf("\\textcolor{%s}{%s}", color, x)
 } else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
 sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>", 
 color,
 x)
 } else x
 }
 ```
 This is a _sample_ book written in **Markdown** with `r colorize("desired red text", "red")`.
````

this appears somewhat more promising as (1) it does compile and (2) the desired text is red.  However, the colorize function actually appears in the book (since it's in the body of the markdown) and the colorize function only works within the same chapter in which it is placed.

Obviously the goal is to have the colorize function *work* while *not actually appearing* in the rendered book, and we also want the color to work across all chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my current solution.

Create a file called _myfunctions.R which contains the colorize function (no tick marks, just the R code below).  Put this file in the same directory as the chapter files.

```
 colorize <- function(x, color) {
 if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
 sprintf("\\textcolor{%s}{%s}", color, x)
 } else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
 sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>", 
 color,
 x)
 } else x
 }
```

Now, in every chapter .Rmd file, put the following code so that your functions are sourced into the chapter.

````
 ```{r echo=FALSE}
 source('_myfunctions.R')
 ```
````

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide the R stuff, try this for your first line:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
````

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Using the echo option in the header of the colorize function works in order to hide the R code.  Now I just need to solve the separate problem of getting the same function to be usable across chapters.  This link implies I need to create a package, or read in a script, so not sure, but I'm working to figure this out. https://community.rstudio.com/t/bookdown-variables-across-chapters-rmd-files/7857