# How to eliminate incompatible color warnings in R bookdown?

Tags: r, latex, bookdown

I'm using RBookdown with multiple chapters such as [this minimal example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo).

After successfully implementing [the custom block instructions here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/custom-blocks.html#block-shaded) everything looks great.  The boxes appear in both html and pdf formats, as intended.

However, I am using color fonts across the document, and upon inclusion of the latex custom block preamble items.

```
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}

 \newtcolorbox{blackbox}{
   colback=black,
   colframe=orange,
   coltext=white,
   boxsep=5pt,
   arc=4pt}
```

now the compile error appears as

```
Warning: Package xcolor Warning: Incompatible color definition on input line 215.
```

I see no problems with the colors, they are all working as intended.  Similar for the custom blocks, they all appear fine.  Unless anyone has a better suggestion, I will just ignore the xcolor warnings.

I found similar discussions [here](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3802) and [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/problem-with-unicode-in-rmarkdown/61169) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150369/incompatible-color-definition-when-using-tikz-with-color-package) but I still haven't found any fix to the error messages.

Note:  Color is implemented using the solution [in previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73466050/how-to-use-custom-function-for-color-text-across-all-chapters-of-rbookdown)

UPDATE:  To create MWE, use [this minimal example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo)
and edit the index.Rmd file to look as follows

````
 --- 
 title: "A Minimal Book Example"
 author: "Yihui Xie"
 date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
 site: bookdown::bookdown_site
 output: 
   bookdown::html_book
 documentclass: book
 bibliography: [book.bib, packages.bib]
 biblio-style: apalike
 link-citations: yes
 github-repo: rstudio/bookdown-demo
 description: "This is a minimal example of using the bookdown package to write a book. The output format for this example is bookdown::gitbook."
 ---
 ```{r echo=FALSE}
 colorize <- function(x, color) {
 if (knitr::is_latex_output()) {
 sprintf("\\textcolor{%s}{%s}", color, x)
 } else if (knitr::is_html_output()) {
 sprintf("<span style='color: %s;'>%s</span>",
 color,
 x)
 } else x
 }
 ```
 # Prerequisites
 
 This is a _sample_ book written in **Markdown**. You can use anything that Pandoc's Markdown supports, e.g., a math equation $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$.   This is a _sample_ book written in **Markdown** with `r colorize("desired brown text", "brown")` which appears as intended.
````

Then also edit the preamble.tex file to include the line below.

```
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
```

Then use R command

```
 bookdown::render_book("index.Rmd", "bookdown::pdf_book")
```

to compile into pdf, and the described errors will appear.

Comment: Please make a [mre] that allows us to reproduce the problem. The problem is probably that rmarkdown will automatically load the xcolor package and then something later tries to load it with conflicting options

Comment: Update has been added to OP including MWE.